# Is it harmful if I chose to drive 2WD mode for my 4WD Renault Duster specifically when I am driving in the city?

Tags: renault, 4wd, 2wd, duster

I got a new [Renault Duster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renault_Duster_Oroch) 4x4 car 2021, where I have a control with three options:

1. 2WD.
2. Auto.
3. Lock (4WD).

Now when I am driving in the city I chose the 2WD, but if I am driving out side the city (not off-roading) I turn it to *Lock* mode as the feel that the car will have more performance outside the city roads, and I rarely put the control on the auto mode. So can my driving modes harm the car parts? Mainly I do 2WD inside the city roads + 4WD when I am outside the city, I do not do off-roading.

Comment: Realistically, if they didn't want you to use the 2WD mode, they wouldn't offer it as an option. As Mike states, use 4WD only when conditions warrant. Sounds like you don't need it much at all, realistically.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 basically i got the 4WD car not because of the 4WD, but because the 4WD car comes with 2,000 CC engine while the 2WD car comes with 1,600 CC. so i wanted the larger engine CC.

Comment: Oh, no judgements from me. I'd have done the same thing :o)

Comment: You don't need the lock unless you go offroad, so you can stop doing that in most conditions.

Comment: @Mast so what is the most recommended way is this case to use 2WD or Auto?

Comment: For most conditions (on dry road and not hauling anything), 2WD will suffice. That's the 'normal car' setting.

Comment: awesome vehicle, BTW !

Comment: @Mast Not arguing against, I have a selective awd car, but as relevant information; I always thought you should take care to use 4wd option now and then - the force applying tires wear at a different rate - and too large dimension difference can be hard on the drive chain. A small difference will be "corrected" (well, overwear actually) by the torque applied when driving 4WD.

Comment: Use Auto mode; the beards at Renault probably did a much better job of programming the car to know when to use each, unless you specifically know you need one mode or the other. A good rule of thumb is "unless you have support, go as far as you can in 2WD, then if you get stuck, use 4WD to get out and go back". From the driving you've said youre doing you'll probably never need 4WD

Comment: 4WD lock winds up the transmission on sealed roads as soon as your front and rear tyres start to show different wear. It can lead to the transmission breaking. The manual can't be more clear about this. Fortunately, the Duster disangages 4WD-lock on your behalf when you start driving over 60km/h for one minute.

Answer (score 30):

Use 2wd unless conditions need 4wd.

Check the user manual as that will probably say the same.

Driving the extra drivetrain is wasteful on fuel, which is why many (often older) 4wd have autolock hubs either original spec or aftermarket.

Just to be clear, there are hub locks which can be auto or manual and are fitted at the wheel end of the front axle, which means that the front wheels can rotate without having to rotate the front diff, halfshafts and prop shaft back to the transfer box.

Locking diffs have also been around a while, with the most common being a locking centre diff only. There are some vehicles that have locking diffs front and rear but that can cause more serious damage on hard surfaces (seen locking diffs explode due to the forces applied when tires don't slip...).

There are also viscous couplings used which may or may not have fancy electronic control. These tend to be **very** expensive when they break...

Comment: thanks for the reply .. so what is the most recommended way is this case to use 2WD or Auto?

Comment: @testtest "Use 2wd unless conditions need 4wd."

Comment: @J... hub locks are not differential locks.

Comment: The *Renault Duster Handbook* does not say the same.  In fact, it has an explicit warning, in a box on page 2.14, in addition to guidance on page 2.11.

Comment: @JdeBP, why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @SolarMike so you mean no need to use the Auto mode?

Answer (score 15):

1. **Don't use "Lock (4WD)" mode unless on soft terrain.**

You will get increased wear of tyres and transmission, worse directional stability and higher fuel consumption for nothing in return.

There is an automatic function that disables "lock" at high speeds, but it is only a safety measure and not a replacement for a reasonable driver choice.

"Locked" 4WD car handles turns impressively bad, up to and including a complete loss of directional control and going out of the lane or road.

"Locked" is only for sand, mud or some cases of snow and only for use below 30km/h.

2. Auto is good everywhere. That's why it is called "Auto". It may fail to engage rear wheels hard enough when the terrain is especially bad (mud, sand, heavy snow) and that's why "Lock" mode exists.
3. 2WD is good on hard, clean, dry, paved road. You will get about 1 litter per 100km better economy in exchange for slightly worse start from still. It runs almost like any other front-wheel driven car.

Comment: thanks for the reply and the info, so what is the most recommended way is this case to use 2WD or Auto?

Comment: I would use Auto almost everywhere. 2WD for long trips on good roads in good weather. But I don't know what roads in your place look like. It may as well be better 2WD everywhere and Auto only when it rains.

Answer (score 14):

> i do 2WD inside the city roads + 4WD when i am out side the city, i do not do off roading

You'll get better performance and efficiency in 2WD mode, especially on faster roads outside the city.

You should leave it in 2WD unless there is ice or snow on the road.

If you live in a country where roads outside the city are mostly slow bumpy gravel or loose-dirt roads, then you should use 4WD and low speeds on those bad roads.

Comment: thanks for the reply and the info, so what is the most recommended way is this case to use 2WD or Auto?

Comment: @testtest if I often had to switch to 4WD and back to 2WD, I'd just leave it in auto. If 99% of my driving was on paved highway (tarmac) I'd just leave it in 2WD all the time. If I was ever driving off-road through deep mud, deep dry sand or up a steep grassy hillside I'd only then manually engage 4WD. As an example of my use of a somewhat equivalent feature, I see a small amount of ice (or risk of ice) on roads maybe a couple of times a year, that's the only time I ever use my car's "all-weather" mode.

Comment: Even with ice and snow on the road, 4WD will only help to accelerate or to get you moving from stuck or stopped.  4WD only helps you to speed up.  It won't help you steer, hold the road, turn, or slow down.  Winter tires for winter.

Comment: Strictly speaking, 4WD only helps if your tire tractions are different between your front and back tires (read: off-road). It really doesn't help much on bad snow conditions because all your tires are on bad road. Compared to proper tires, I would take a 2WD with snow tires over a 4WD on "all season" any day.

Comment: @Nelson No, that's not true. 2x driven wheels means 2x contact patch, which means even if the friction of the road surface is low, you still get 2x that low traction when you drive 2x the wheels.  If your front wheels only have half the traction of the rear wheels, then you get 1.5x traction, for example - it's still more, unless your front wheels are completely frictionless (in which case, I think you have bigger problems...).

Comment: Realistically, 4WD _can_ help with steering by removing some of the load from the front tires while accelerating.  That said, in slippery conditions you shouldn't be accelerating while steering anyway.

Comment: @Turksarama Yes, 4WD helps you to go *faster* (ie: more performance while accelerating).  That's all.

Comment: Do 133HP Duster owners ever manage to lose traction and spin the front wheels in 2WD mode in normal use on dry roads in good conditions? I'd expect engaging 4WD slows you down unless conditions are slippery and you are trying for a racing start.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick 133hp is surely enough to spin the front tires of a small FWD car.  FWD want to bunny-hop, so acceleration actually lifts the front end and reduces your front wheel traction (squatting onto the rear tires during acceleration).  Maybe something like soft slicks could still hold the road, but even with moderately performant street tires it's nothing to chirp first or second gear in a tiny 130-140hp FWD car.

Answer (score 8):

The Renault/Dacia Duster uses the same [4x4 system as Nissan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacia_Duster#Renault_Duster_Oroch)

> The Duster is offered with two-wheel drive or four-wheel-drive. The 4x4 variants make use of Nissan's all-wheel drive system,[10] which allows the driver to choose from three different driving modes: Auto, in which the rear-wheel drive is engaged automatically in case the front wheels lose grip, Lock, whereby 50 per cent of torque is consistently fed through the rear axle, and 2WD where the transmission is locked into front-wheel drive for maximum fuel efficiency.

From the Duster's user manual:

> "AUTO" mode automatically distributes the engine torque between the front and rear axles according to the road conditions and the vehicle speed. This position optimises road holding. Use this mode on any type of road (dry, snow-covered, slippery, etc.) or when towing(trailer or caravan).

> > "2WD" mode.  Operating principle The "2WD" mode uses the front wheels only. Use this mode on dry roads with good grip

> > > Operating principle "4WD Lock" mode distributes the engine torque between the front and rear axles in order to optimise the performance capacity of the vehicle in off-road situations. This mode should only be used in extreme driving conditions(mud, steep slopes, sand).
> > > Note: if the vehicle speed exceeds 36 mph (60 km/h) in 4WD Lock mode,the system automatically switches back to AUTO mode.

You shouldn't feel any significant performance difference between 2WD and 4WD under normal conditions, the Duster is not a high performance car and you probably won't drive it at high speed on slaloms. If anything fuel consumption can be a bit higher with 4WD turned on, and the transmission would have a bit more wear.

As stated above using Lock mode CAN harm your car, more wear and tear on the tires and transmission, but most chances are that you are not really using it since it disconnects itself at 60 KMH.

The handbook I looked at is slightly different than @JdeBP mentioned, but here's a qoute:

> All-wheel drive system– Irrespective of the mode selected, do not start the engine if one or more wheels are not in contact with the ground(eg. when the vehicle is on a jack or roller bench).– Do not turn the mode selector when cornering, reversing or if the wheels are spinning excessively. Only select the"2WD", "AUTO" or "4WD Lock" mode when the vehicle is being driven in a straight line.– Only use tyres which meet the required specifications.– "4WD Lock" mode is reserved solely for use off-road. The use of this mode in any other conditions may adversely affect thevehicle's manoeuvrability and damage its mechanical components.– Always ensure tyres with identical specifications are fitted to all four wheels (brand, size, structure, wear etc.). Fitting tyresof different sizes to the front and rear wheels and/or left and right wheels may have serious consequences for the tyres,gearbox, transfer gearbox and the rear differential pinions

To summarize as other mentioned, use 2WD unless you are driving in heavy rain, snow or ice and read the driver manual.

Comment: thanks for the reply and the detailed info, so what is the most recommended way is this case to use 2WD or Auto?

Comment: 2WD most of the time, AUTO on roads during rough weather/conditions like snow, heavy rain etc, Lock only when driving off-road on soft surfaces like sand or gravel or when getting stuck

Comment: You've missed the actual answer to the question, which is in a warning box on page 2.14 of the handbook.

Comment: *"the Duster is not a high performance car and you probably won't drive it at high speed on slaloms"*  CLASSIC !

Comment: @JdeBP You could post that as answer, quoting the manual.

Answer (score 8):

I will offer a counter-point to all of the current answers which indicate using 2WD "except when you need 4WD".

In general, I will agree that 4WD isn't necessary and the 2WD (front wheels driven) mode is sufficient, as is attested by the fact that the majority of vehicles built today are front-wheel drive.

However, "when you need" 4WD could be in an emergency situation where the ability of having the rear wheels powered *can* help with handling (note: this means acceleration or cornering to avoid the accident, *not* braking - 4WD does *nothing* to improve braking<sup>*</sup>), thus, *potentially* avoiding an accident. Therefore, I'd suggest leaving it in "Auto" mode all the time.

According to the [Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dacia_Duster#First_generation_(HS;_2010)) (as originally linked by [rsf](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/79917/32126)) Auto distributes power *as needed*. In an emergency situation, there often isn't time for the driver to *remember* to hit the 4WD button/switch to say anything of actually hitting it.

Additionally, while it's a nice idea, most people won't remember to switch to "Auto" or "4WD" on a rainy or snowy day, thereby completely negating the purpose of lugging around all the extra hardware (and reducing fuel economy *all* the time by having a heavier vehicle).

If fuel efficiency is of significant concern (and I'd suspect it's *less* important to this OP, who specifically chose the model with the larger engine), I'd recommend doing a bit of personal testing, keeping track of your mileage (kilometerage?) for a month (or at least 2 full tanks of fuel) using 2WD mode, then a month using Auto mode to see if there's a significant enough difference to *you*. Your efficiency <s>may</s> will vary from officially published numbers, so test it out in your regular driving routine. Some may be willing to sacrifice 10% fuel economy for the potential safety benefits, others may be willing to sacrifice more, and others less. My bet is that the difference between 2WD and Auto mode will be negligible, while full-time 4WD would be more noticeable.

---

<sup>*</sup> The lack of effectiveness of 4WD on braking is evidenced by the number of 4WD vehicles I see in the ditches during the winter where I live in the Midwest US vs the number of FWD/RWD cars I see. People seem to think 4WD/AWD makes them invincible on snow & ice. It most certainly does not.

Comment: Your last paragraph basically points out that while a vehicle may be capable, the single brain cell mammal driving it may not be. What was that Fiat ad? Designed by computer, built by Robots, driven by monkeys :)

Comment: I don't see a whole lot of commercials @SolarMike, especially not for Fiats (they haven't sold 'em in the US in _ages_, but I like that one!

Comment: so many people think 4wd means they dont need snow tires... until i pull them out of a ditch with a rear wheel drive car with snow tires and they finally get it

Comment: The only correct answer! (Uh, except mine!  :) )

Comment: one point, @FreeMan , most 4WD systems most definitely affect braking - you get engine braking to all four wheels.

Comment: Well, I'd considered that, @Fattie. However, in the US, at least, there aren't that many manuals available (trust me, it takes forever to find one!), and with an automatic, you really don't get much benefit from engine braking.

Comment: that's a good point..

Comment: @Fattie While you do get four-wheel engine braking with 4WD engaged, you do not get a larger maximum retarding force, as this is determined by the tire-to-surface friction. Pre-ABS, a skilled driver may have occasionally been able to exploit the different fore-and-aft balance of retarding forces that 4WD engine braking gives, but ABS makes that moot.

Comment: SD, "you do not get a larger maximum retarding force, as this is determined by the tire-to-surface friction" ah, if that were true there would be no need to have disk or drum brakes on more than one wheel :)  With more tires braking, you have greater (1/2, 1/3, 1/4) force available before static friction changes to kinetic friction (ie, it slides :) )

Comment: @Fattie Your logic is flawed (to put it mildly!) Why do you think the proposition "you do not get a larger maximum retarding force, as this is determined by the tire-to-surface friction" implies the conclusion "if that were true there would be no need to have disk or drum brakes on more than one wheel"? In fact, it follows from the premise that maximum braking occurs if and only if each and every wheel is creating its maximum retarding force. It is immaterial to the value of that maximum whether that is achieved by brakes, engine braking, or a combination.

Comment: @Fattie So, 4WD engine braking does not help to achieve maximum braking (and it may make it impossible to get the balance right). There is one scenario in which it might help: when the engine-braking torque is sufficient to cause the tires of the driven wheels to slip when distributed over two wheels, but not when distributed over four. Given ABS, the practical consequence of this is that you should be cautious using engine braking in slippery condiditions, and use the brakes instead, taking advantage of ABS.

Comment: hi SD, you incorrectly said *"with [four wheel braking, versus two] you do not get a larger maximum retarding force, as this is determined by the tire-to-surface friction"*. (in that sentence, it makes no difference what form of braking is being used .. engine, regenerative, disk, drum etc).  It may be you misspoke, otherwise, ask on physics.SE! With more tires braking, you have greater (1/2, 1/3, 1/4) force available before static friction changes to kinetic friction (ie, it slides :) )

Comment: @Fattie Here's a hint of where you are going wrong: you had to insert your own words into what I wrote to come up with a false statement. If you read everything I wrote *and nothing more*, you will not find a mistake.

Comment: Ah, this sentence "While you do get four-wheel engine braking with 4WD engaged, you do not get a larger maximum retarding force, as this is determined by the tire-to-surface friction." is incorrect. (It's also incorrect if one is talking simply of normal brakes.)  Whenever you have more tires braking, you get "more braking" because you reduce the max. force on the braking tires.  (Also importantly, if one or more is skipping / lightening you obviously have more still with downforce!)

Comment: @Fattie Please explain what other forces are relevant.  I see you are still misreading my comment, as if it contained the language that you erroneously inserted, or an implication thereof. Consequently, the rest of what you write is beside the point.

Comment: @fattie Here are the facts: 1) the maximum retarding force is the sum of the maximum each tire can achieve. 2) The maximum each tire can achieve is dependent on its material, its geometry and the state of the road it is in contact with. In particular, it is not dependent on how the retarding torque is generated. 3)  From 1 and 2, the maximum acheivable retarding force is not dependent on how the retarding torque is generated.  You seem to understand this (though not all its implications); what you keep on getting wrong is comprehending correctly what I wrote, without making invalid assumptions

Comment: Hmm, are you thinking of engine braking *at the same time* ("with") friction (disk, drum) braking?

Comment: Let me put it this way. Car is going along at X mph and we remove all feet from all pedals. One is now experiencing engine braking.  *(Everything here applies for any form of braking.)*  The momentum of the vehicle is now working against the N tires which are braking -> creating F force on each individual of the N tires.  If N is larger, that force F is less.  If F gets too big, it will skid.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113588/discussion-on-answer-by-freeman-is-it-harmful-if-i-chose-to-drive-2wd-mode-for-m).

Answer (score 1):

In a traditional 4x4 vehicle like this 4wd will only benefit you in gaining traction on a loose surface.  Use 4wd when youre stuck or there's wheel slip otherwise it just extra fuel youre using.  Find a safe place to try it out.  The low range gives you more torque which is helpful when climbing a steep grade or when the snow/mud/sand is thick enough that you don't have the power to drive through. Most people don't need these features and the manufactures have learned this by making crossover suvs that reflect how people really use their trucks.  If you do live somewhere with rough terrain the old 4x4 is awesome.

Comment: The duster (and most soft 4x4's) don't have a low range

Answer (score 1):

Many people just don't get it...

There are only two positions you should be using for the way you described your driving, 2WD and AUTO. 2WD will save gas mileage and wear and tear on the driveline. Auto sets the driveline into *all wheel drive*. This is meant for better control on road and for inclement weather, such as wet pavement and snow.

*Lock* should *never* be used on-road as it will mess up your driveline in short order, especially if you have a manual (stick) transmission. The only time you would engage lock on road is if the road is so snow-covered that your tires are running on fresh snow and not even touching the road surface and auto just isn't helping. In this instance, it's just like driving on loose soil or sand where there isn't a prepared roadbed. If you are driving on hard-packed snow use *Auto*.

Here is a hint from a hardcore four-wheel-drive vehicle owner and builder: my *jeeps* are built up for serious offroading and in over fifty years of driving and playing off-road, even teaching my daughters to drive in mud fields before they were old enough to get their learners permits, the big point is you never use *Lock* ***except*** to get out of what the other options you have got you into.

If you are stuck, and you are in *Lock*, you now have to pay someone to get you out. That is unless the road is so bad with snow as I previously stated and you have no choice, in order to find away off the highway, to somewhere safe, to wait it out.

Bear in mind, *my* tires are four foot tall and made for stuff like this, I've even gotten phone calls from the local police during blizzards asking me to come pull squad cars out of ditches because of the way my jeeps are built, and the towing service they have a contract with won't come out.

We live on the shore of one of the Great Lakes, just below Canada, in the US, in the blizzard zone, and I don't mean [Dairy Queen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dairy_Queen)! Over stressing light equipment *will* damage it. Your car is light equipment, and driving on pavement in lock is putting extreme stress on it. Never admit to doing it to a dealer or authorized mechanic as it will void your warranty.

Comment: so you mean when i use Auto it is not like using 2WD or 4WD? i thought Auto means that the car will run as 2WD or as 4WD depend on the road.. but are you saying that Auto will be different than 2WD or 4WD? let say i am driving in a normal road at the speed of 70-80 km/hour then will 2WD and Auto differ?

Comment: Your car uses a Nissan/Renault differential [see here under Qashqai 2007-2013](https://www.awdwiki.com/en/nissan/), the front back ratio is [explained here](https://www.awdwiki.com/en/dacia/) TLDR; AUTO is 2x4 until the car "feels" a slip between the front and back.

Comment: Answering the first comment : ON THE DUSTER, using "2WD" completely frees the rear wheels. Using "Auto" drives the rear wheels through an electronically controlled viscous coupling, and can improve traction, including on sealed roads, especially when towing. Using "lock" locks the front and rear axles together, and can quickly break the transmission on sealed roads. "Lock" on the Duster is the same as the "lock" on the Jeeps described in this answer, with the same pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

Those gears and all gears should be used once in awhile. My opinion is, if something isn’t used for a long period of time it or they can go to hell! Like gaskets or! On automatic transmissions the fluid is ran through the system better when you use the gears. Just like checking your automatic trans. You Change gears as the engine is running so the fluid will run thru the system better and then you check it! Change gears once in a while! Just my opinion!  Won’t hurt!

Answer (score 0):

The labelled "Auto" mode on a Duster is a "smart" 4WD mode.  (For want of a better term.)

Leave it in "Auto" and forget it forever.

There's almost literally NEVER a need to select "2WD!".

(Indeed, it's a bit silly they bothered to include a "2WD!" mode.)

So, like, 50 years ago folks would say things like,

- Don't leave your auto in "D" at the traffic lights!
- Check All Fluid Levels if you leave your vehicle parked for more than 2 days!
- Learn these Hand Signals in case the Relay on your Indicators breaks during Driving!

It's all unnecessary today.

It's impossible you could notice any (say) efficiency difference in 2WD mode.

## Dangerous to muck about with...

Indeed let's consider this hypothetical:

## An imaginary "better braking system" ...

Say that your car had ***two "braking systems"***.

You have "normal" brakes, and also "better" brakes.

Incredibly, there's a switch between "normal" and "better".

It comes from the factory on "better".

You hear that in theory if you select "normal" it will save a penny a day.

Would you ever select "normal" brakes?

The analogy makes it clear that, in a Dacia Duster, it's great to just leave it alone on "Auto" which is "smart" 4WD.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but there is not a mode for Auto-4WD, there are 2 separate modes Auto and 4WD..

Comment: thanks @testtest - sorry, what I meant was the "normal" 4WD mode !  (which is smart - and you can just leave it on that)

Comment: you mean the Auto mode?

Comment: for sure, @testtest - set it to Auto mode and forget it.  it is the most efficient overall, and, safest